# Jmeter performance Testing the Apps that use BOTS

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, rpa

I have a scenario where in I have to perform perf testing on the application that will use computerized software robots(RPA) to handle some of the functions of application. I need to come up with test plan and provide an over view on how the bots will impact the application.

Currently , I have Jmeter set up for testing the application. I have a performance base line established and most of the APIs are being tested in my current suite. The goal is to ensure that the bots don't degrade the performance of the applications if they are used for certain functions within the application.
The bots export reports on daily basis , Some bots download reports and some perform few work flow functions. Should I run the perf test while the bots are being run or should I establish base line first . Any feed back is appreciated.

currently planning to run perf base line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to conduct 2 [load tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing):

1. First when the application is not being used by bots
2. And the second when the application is being used by bots

and compare the [metrics](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) of your application so you could see the impact.

Going forward you can consider putting your JMeter script under continuous integration pipeline using i.e. [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) and [Performance Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance/), this way you won't need to run tests manually each time and you will be automatically notified about eventual performance degradation.